# debug kernel module (memory corruption_

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I'm debugging my kernel module, which appears to have a memory corruption, 
basically a piece of memory allocated by alloc_netdev() for 'net_device' 
instance has been corrupted.

1) I turned on `CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_SLAB`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK` in my kernel's `.config`, however not sure what to expect from `kmemleak`. Is it supposed to print out a trace dump of suspected memory leaks whenever I read `/sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak`? Is there a way to reset the statistics/information accumulated by `kmemleak`? An the most important -- could anyone help to decipher the output, e.g. :

```
unreferenced object 0xc625e000 (size 2048):
  comm "swapper", pid 1, jiffies 4294937521
  backtrace:
    [<c00c89f0>] create_object+0x11c/0x200
    [<c00c6764>] __kmalloc_track_caller+0x138/0x178
    [<c01d78c0>] __alloc_skb+0x4c/0x100
    [<c01d8490>] dev_alloc_skb+0x18/0x3c
    [<c0198b48>] eth_rx_fill+0xd8/0x3fc
    [<c019ac74>] mv_eth_start_internals+0x30/0xf8
    [<c019c5fc>] mv_eth_start+0x70/0x244
    [<c019c810>] mv_eth_open+0x40/0x64
    [<c01e00f0>] dev_open+0xb4/0x118
    [<c01df788>] dev_change_flags+0x90/0x168
    [<c001a3e4>] ip_auto_config+0x1bc/0xecc
    [<c00212f4>] do_one_initcall+0x5c/0x1bc
    [<c00083d0>] kernel_init+0x8c/0x108
    [<c0022f58>] kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8
    [<ffffffff>] 0xffffffff
```

2) I was also wondering if I could apply some "read-only" attribute on this memory, this way I expect to have `Oops` generated when someone tries to modify the memory. Does it sound reasonable?

Appreciate any advices, thanks.

Mark

Comment: Great question and answer: the general question is: how to debug a kernel memory leak / memory corruption ?

Comment: there was an option in the kernel to get it spit out proper stacktraces (i.e. line information). which usually makes it alot easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To catch incorrect memory accesses, [KAsan](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kasan.txt) or [kmemcheck](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kmemcheck.txt) could probably be more useful. Note that Kmemcheck, however, is known to incur a significant which may sometimes be unacceptable, so it is up to you to decide. KASan should be much faster.

1.
Concerning kmemleak, its operation is described in detail in the [kernel docs](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kmemleak.txt).

In short, it is more reliable to execute

```
echo scan > /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak
```

as root to trigger memory analysis immediately before you read `/sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak`. Sometimes, I found even more reliable to execute the above command twice before reading kmemleak's report.

To "reset" the data collected by kmemleak, you can execute

```
echo clear > /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak
```

The output you have posted means that kmemleak thinks that a memory area 2Kb in size at address `0xc625e000` has not been freed at the time the tool has last analyzed memory. The backtrace specifies where the memory was allocated. "swapper" is the name of the process that has allocated that memory area.

2.
As far as setting memory read-only is concerned, this technique is indeed used in some places of the kernel, e.g. to protect the code of the kernel proper and the modules. I cannot give you exact instructions here but the implementation of [set_page_attributes() function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=set_page_attributes) is a good place to start digging in.

Note that kmemcheck I mentioned above uses a somewhat similar technique to track memory accesses: makes pages "look" like they do not exist so that each access to them causes a page fault, etc. The details are in the [kernel docs](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kmemcheck.txt), as usual.

Comment: Eugene, thank you for the valuable information. However it looks that kmemcheck is available only on x86 platform, while I'm facing the memory corruption only on ARM platform when running the code; similarly it appears that set_page_attributes() exists in kernels 2.6.38+ and also only for x86 arch, while I'm on 2.6.31.

Comment: Ah, I supposed the machine had x86 architecture. Added "arm" tag to your question to make it more obvious. Perhaps, ARM experts here could give more advice.